# Windows 2008 Server Standard receiving and sending a huge amount of data

Tags: traffic, network-traffic

I have this Windows 2008 Server I've just installed a couple of weeks ago and right now I'm starting to configure and prepare it to be PDC.
I've clicked on the network and I've seen packets coming and going super fast O_O

How can I read easily what's going on just on this computer?

I would like to understand better who generates all this traffic and why.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answerable question.  You might want to pick something specific to ask about - a particular item in the traffic you see in your packet analyzer, perhaps.

Comment: I just want to understand what program or service does that lot of sending and receiving data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pitto,

My favorite tool for really checking the activity of a machine is Process Explorer.

You can download it here.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

In 2008 you have some built in functionality as well but this tool is powerful and I would really suggest you look into the current state of it.

rgs.
.am

Comment: I'll check it! Thanks... I'll be back with news :)